# Unable to unzip my file on Ubuntu 20.04 server

Tags: command-line, server, 20.04, tar, zip

Unable to unzip my file on Ubuntu 20.04 server. Why doesn't it work, what's missing ? Thank you

```
ubuntu@ov-67g764:/tmp$ sudo wget https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/lucene/solr/8.6.1/solr-8.6.1.tgz
ubuntu@ov-67g764:/tmp$ sudo tar xzf solr-8.6.1.tgz solr-8.6.1/bin/install_solr_service.sh --strip-components=2

gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

**UPDATE :**

```
ubuntu@ov-67g764:/tmp$ sudo wget https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/lucene/solr/8.6.1/solr-8.6.1.tgz
--2020-09-06 21:51:20--  https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/lucene/solr/8.6.1/solr-8.6.1.tgz
Resolving www.apache.org (www.apache.org)... 40.79.78.1, 95.216.24.32, 2a01:4f9:2a:185f::2
Connecting to www.apache.org (www.apache.org)|40.79.78.1|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘solr-8.6.1.tgz’

solr-8.6.1.tgz                         [ <=>                                                             ]  14.22K  --.-KB/s    in 0.1s    

2020-09-06 21:51:22 (140 KB/s) - ‘solr-8.6.1.tgz’ saved [14562]
```

Comment: What does `file solr-8.6.1.tgz` report? many sites "hide" downloads behind a web link, so that `wget` ends up downloading an HTML file instead

Comment: @steeldriver I updated the question, you must be right. Which command line should I use to download the file ?

Comment: Well, according to the HTML page, *"The requested file or directory is not on the mirrors. The object is in our archive :"* https://archive.apache.org/dist/lucene/solr/8.6.1/solr-8.6.1.tgz